# docker stack deploy doesn't use overlay network created

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, swarm

I created an overlay network using this command:

```
docker network create --driver overlay --internal --subnet 192.168.0.0/24 test
```

and then I tried deploying a stack with one service. the stack's yaml file looks like:

```
---
version: "3.0"
services:
  web1:
    image: "test"
    ports:
       - "12023:22"
    hostname: "ard014-web1"
    networks:
      - test
networks:
  test:
    driver: overlay
```

I deploy the stack using the command:

```
docker stack deploy -c test.yaml test
```

if I check the networks with docker network ls I find new overlay network gets created with name test_test and the container uses this network instead of the already created one. is this an expected behavior? I want the stack to use the network I created manually instead of creating new network because I want to control the ip CIDR range used by the overlay network. how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To use an existing network, define it as "external":

```
version: "3.0"
services:
  web1:
    image: "test"
    ports:
       - "12023:22"
    hostname: "ard014-web1"
    networks:
      - test
networks:
  test:
    external: 
      name: test
```

More details here: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#external-1

Comment: I noticed that I can use this on containers that already been created to change its network. I got the error message "Error response from daemon: rpc error: code = 2 desc = changing network in service is not supported"

Comment: @tkyass There are technical reasons for that, perhaps the service VIP would not work with a rolling upgrade. The fix is to just delete the existing service when making a change like this.